# Why are parts of my program ignored?

Tags: if-statement, netbeans, while-loop

I've been working on this program that is supposed to take a list of integers entered by the user and the program states the maximum, minimum, and average of the numbers entered. The average part works fine, but for some reason, when the program reaches the max and min parts it just skips them.

```
/*
Program that takes a list of numbers entered by the user and 
states the largest, smallest, and average of these numbers.
*/
package main1;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
*
* @author M.Jalil
*/
public class Main1 {

   /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
   public static void main(String[] args) {

    int next; // next number entered by user
    double min = 100; // initialized min
    double max = 0; // initilized max
    double sum; //sum of numbers entered by user
    int numbers; // amount of numbers entered by user
    double average; //calculated average of numbers entered by users

    System.out.println("Enter a list of positive numbers.");
    System.out.println("Enter a negative number when you're done.");

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    next = kb.nextInt();
    numbers = 0;
    sum = 0;

    //finds the sum of all numbers and amount of numbers entered
    while (next >= 0) {
        sum = sum + next;
        numbers++;
        next = kb.nextInt();
        int[] list = new int[numbers]; // an array list of the numbers entered
        list[numbers] = next;

        // checks if number entered is bigger than the max number and assigns the larger number to max
        if (list[numbers] > max) {
            max = list[numbers];
            System.out.println("Max number: " + max); // displays maximum number ||**ignored??**||
        }
        //checks if number entered is less than the min number and assigns the smaller number to min
        if (list[numbers] < min) {
            min = list[numbers];
            System.out.println("Min number: " + min); //displays minimum number  ||**ignored??**||
        } 

    }
    average = sum / numbers; // calculates average

    System.out.println("The average is: " + average);

}
```

}

I've labeled the parts print lines that are ignored and don't show on the screen as they are supposed to. Can anyone take a look over this and help me out? I feel like the issue may be with my parameters, but I'm not really sure what's going on. Thanks in advance for any info or advice.

Answer (score 0):

Parts of your program are not "ignored" -- the condition in your if statements must equate to false at runtime

Comment: But it cant be false because the max value is assigned to 0. The numbers I enter are greater than 0 which make this a true statement. Unless the problem is with the value of the 'list[numbers]' variable. From the way I have it set, does the 'list[numbers]' variable equal the numbers assigned into 'next' which are the keyboard inputs?

Comment: Erwin - I've clarified my post.  I don't think its helpful to go into more detail then this as it would complete this person's homework assignment... Cheers